# In MongoDB how to return one first document for each existing field's value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

```
{ "_id": "1122", "qty": 5, "used" : 0 }
{ "_id": "1221", "qty": 7, "used" : 0 }
{ "_id": "1122", "qty": 42, "used" : 0 }
{ "_id": "1221", "qty": 35, "used" : 0 }
{ "_id": "1223", "qty": 26, "used" : 0 }
{ "_id": "1223", "qty": 15, "used" : 0 }
```

How to get by one document with field "used" = 0, for each passible value of "_id" field, and increment it. So i want first get by one from every documents values "_id" , increment "used" fild, and whenn ("used" = 0)s are finished start the same process with ("used" = 1)s  e.t.c ...
I watched something helpfull in this answers
[first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254039/how-to-retrieve-a-value-from-mongodb-by-its-key-name),
[next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123259/most-efficient-way-to-get-all-value-for-a-field-in-mongodb-node-js), but still in searching.
I'm using mongojs . Maybe  there is special solution for this kind of action that i' trying to set?

Answer (score 0):

In your JS file use this code.

```
 var myCursor = db.collectionname.find( { "used": 0 } );
while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
print(tojson(myCursor.next()));
}
```